# Все также король... или так же?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Все также король... или так же?

Answer (score 1):

Недостаточно слов в примере, чтобы сложился контекст.

**Так же** - это как уже было: *Всё так же король просил на завтрак бутерброд с маслом.*

**Также** - это тоже, в придачу, некий повтор: Вдобавок к бутербродам король также любил произведение Александра Алана Милна ["Баллада о королевском бутерброде"](http://a-pesni.org/baby/poesia/marchak.php).

---

[Правописание слов «также» и «так же» зависит от того, какая перед нами часть речи. Правило такое: союз пишется слитно, наречие с частицей – раздельно.](http://pishempravilno.ru/takzhe-i-tak-zhe/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Также король** - это король по совместительству. Всё осталось по-прежнему: он всё властелин мира и всё "(а) также король" - за это хоть платят. :)

Comment: Спасибо, Саша, за "совместительство" - вкусное слово-пример, меня не осенило...

Answer (score 1):

Для примера, можно сказать так: он все так же молод, он все так же работает на заводе и т. п. Здесь сравнение: молод в той же степени, по-прежнему работает на заводе. Обычно "все так же" употребляется с прилагательным или глаголом. Но "он все так же король" звучит коряво. Гораздо лучше: он по-прежнему король.

*Также* означает тоже, в придачу. В сочетании со словом *всё* получается бессмыслица.

> [Вопрос № 255019](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=255019)
>    Вы все также молоды, вы все также вместе. Слово ТАКЖЕ пишется в данном случае слитно?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Слитное написание возможно, если здесь также синонимично слову "тоже".

Answer (score 0):

Ответ изменен

**Вариант 1. ТАК ЖЕ ― местоимение и частица ЖЕ**

**Всё так же король...**

Пример текста:

**Всё так же (как и раньше)** король был бодр и энергичен, **всё так же** начинал  день с утренней пробежки. Подразумевается сравнение: ***так же, как и раньше).***

**Ничего не изменилось, он так же король** (по-прежнему, как и раньше)

**Вариант 2. ТАКЖЕ ― союз**

Его брат на троне, он **также (тоже)** король. Сопоставление одинаковых ситуаций, которые должны быть названы.

Николай II **также** всю жизнь любил охоту, считая ее настоящим мужским занятием. ТАКЖЕ ― присоединительный союз (=***кроме того, вдобавок***)

Comment: Всё также = по-прежнему? Слитно? Откуда такое?

Comment: Вот Пушкин: .".. всё также сух и скучен И груб, и глуп, и завистью размучен..." И еще в Нацкорпусе 150 примеров на "всё также", причем явно в значении "по-прежнему". А на "всё так же" - 3260 примеров. Уж не знаю, что и думать.

Comment: Поиск в Интернете дает два варианта: "всё также сух и скучен" и  "всё так же сух и скучен".  В Нацкорпусе есть "всё также" (у Пелевина, например). Но нет нигде объяснения, оправдывающего слитное написание. Загадка!

Comment: Это не загадка, это неграмотные сайты, а у Пушкина всё верно, раздельно: https://news.rambler.ru/other/40205929/?utm_content=rnews&utm_medium=read_more&utm_source=copylink
  https://difficult_words_ru.academic.ru/734/%E2%97%98 
https://stihi-pushkina.com/zhiv-zhiv-kurilka/

Comment: Раньше не было сайтов (грамотных и неграмотных), а классики использовали это выражение Вот 150 примеров из Нацкорпуса, посмотрите, может быть, найдете нечто загадочное http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%F1%B8+%F2%E0%EA%E6%E5

Comment: Кстати, "всё также сух и скучен =" (= по-прежнему) и "всё так же сух и скучен" (= в такой же степени)  имеют разное значение. Как там у Пушкина на самом деле - неясно, нужен рукописный оригинал. Сравнить:  http://rulibrary.ru/pushkin/perepiska_1815-1825/100